# Access cognito related operations in server-side

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

According to my use case,
I want expose a REST api(auth micro-service) that allows users to signup, sign in and do basic auth operations. So basically when a client calls /auth/login endpoint with username, password server code should authenticate user against Cognito and send response back to client with JWT(access token). Rest api written in Node.js. 
I have gone through various docs but I am only seeing examples of using the frontend/mobile SDKs to accomplish this. Is there a better way to accomplish this? or can use existing javascript SDK in Node.js to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: may be this helps !! https://medium.freecodecamp.org/securing-node-js-restful-apis-with-json-web-tokens-9f811a92bb52

Comment: Thanks for reply but shared blog content not related to aws congnito.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this? Trying to do the same.